# Creating list from array elements, making sequence of numbers

Tags: arrays, algorithm, ocaml

Here's the problem:
I've got numbers like (for example) 3333 222 111. I need to write a program to check if it is possible to make sequence where same numbers are not each others neighbors. Only condition is that first and last elements are known. In this example lets make it 2 and 3. Correct sequence could be 2 32132131 3.

My idea was to put count of middle elements into an array [|3;2;3|], create list via while loop (one method for ascending and another for descending), add first and last element and then check if sequence is correct. There would be a few options in main method - descengind, ascending, reverted etc

Heres some code

```
let makeUp b e arr k= 
  let l = ref [] in
  let i = ref 0 in
  while (List.length !l<k) do
    if arr.(!i) > 0 then l := !i+1 :: !l ; arr.(!i) <- arr.(!i) -1;
    i := (!i + 1) mod Array.length arr; 
  done;
  [b]@(List.rev !l)@[e];;

let rec isCorrect lista =
  match lista with
    [] -> true
  |h::[] -> true
  |h::t -> if (h = List.hd t)then false
    else isCorrect t;;
```

The problem is that I'm modyfing content of an array so I can make list of it only once. Something like this:

```
let find b e array length = 
  if isCorrect(makeUp b e array length) then makeUp b e array length
  else if isCorrect.....
  else [0]
```

simply won't work. I have no idea how to solve this task at all.

Comment: ok, thank you for editing, it was example code to make clear what do I mean but you are right

Comment: Would a program retracing the steps of an analytical solution be considered acceptable?

Comment: I'm not really sure what do you mean :) English is not my first language and I guess I'm missing something, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, to solve you problem in particular, you can use `Array.copy`, that will create a fresh new copy of an array, like this:

```
let makeUp b e arr k =
  let arr = Array.copy arr in
  ...
```

Also, try to not be so imperative and code in more functional style. Don't use while loops and use recursion (or co-recursion) instead to build things.

For example this is a mechanical transformation (I didn't try to understand your algorithm) of your while-loop code, to a more functional:

```
let make b e arr k =
  let arr = Array.copy arr in
  let rec loop xs i len =
    let j = (i + 1) mod Array.length arr in
    if i = k then List.rev (e::xs)
    else if arr.(i) > 0
    then
      let () = arr.(i) <- arr.(i) - 1 in
      loop (i + 1 :: xs) j (len + 1)
    else loop xs j len in
  loop [b] 1 1
```

It has a slight difference though, according to the formating of your code
I assume, that you thin that in expression:

```
 if arr.(!i) > 0 then l := !i+1 :: !l ; arr.(!i) <- arr.(!i) -1;
```

Both assignments will be called under the if guard, in fact, if you will use any tool that indent OCaml correctly you will see that you're wrong:

```
if arr.(!i) > 0 then
  l := !i+1 :: !l;
arr.(!i) <- arr.(!i) - 1;
i := (!i + 1) mod Array.length arr;
```

Only the assignment to the the variable `l` will be performed under the guard. So actually what you want is:

```
if arr.(!i) > 0 then begin
   l := !i+1 :: !l;
   arr.(!i) <- arr.(!i) - 1;
end;
i := (!i + 1) mod Array.length arr;
```

Comment: As I thought, making a copy could be a way. I know that I should use recursion. I'm new to ocaml (fresh programmer at all) and I find it hard to write in C++ in one moment and think functional few seconds later. You are right about my understanding of if expression. Could you tell, what should i do to get result which I expect?

Comment: I  can't because I don't know what do you want ;)

Comment: what I want is
`if arr.(!i) > 0 then
{
   l := !i+1 :: !l;
     arr.(!i) <- arr.(!i) -1;
}
i := (!i + 1) mod Array.length arr;`
Thanks to your help, array is not a problem anymore

Comment: ah, updated the post. OCaml uses `begin/end` or just `()` (parentheses).

Comment: Thank you, program is ready. I mean, it's working, later I should change my loop for sth more functional like you said.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the list sorted in descending order of the cardinality of each element set, couldn't you just keep interspersing the inverted pyramid?

Isn't the only time you could not create such a sequence is if one element appears in greater number (+1) than all others combined?

```
3333 222 111

3 3 3 3
 2 2 2
1 1 1


33333333 222 111

3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
 2 2 2 1 1 1 x
```

Comment: Close. Missed `first and last elements are known` (fixed, pre-set)?

Comment: what i do now is 
3,2 - begin and end   3333 222 111 - all elements ||
descending: 3 21321313 2 CORRECT
ascending:   3 12312313 2 CORRECT
reverted ends desc: 2 13213213 3 INCORRECT (if correct would be reversed)
reverted ends asc: .....
I jusct print first correct, otherwise i should print [o]

Comment: @greybeard oh, right; I did miss that. Doesn't change the basic premise much, though, does it?

Comment: `Doesn't change the basic premise much` - which is why I commented `close`, or about `an analytical solution` in the first place. Fixing/pre-placing elements adds constraints and could be handled by special casing (most frequent element or not) - nothing illuminative crossing my mind.